# How do I upload a next.js blog to ghost

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean, ghost-blog

I am trying to understand how ghost and next.js work together. Basically I created a custom theme blog for ghost using next.js and it works amazing when I upload to a site like [vercel](https://yisroelarnson-blog-vervel.vercel.app/) that builds my blog.

However, when I try and upload my theme to a ghost droplet on Digital ocean it says that I need a default.hbs and a post.hbs. But I don't get how I can integrate those into a next.js blog.

How can I upload my next.js blog to a ghost droplet on digital ocean?

If I can't upload a next.js app to a ghost droplet, can I upload my next.js blog directly to a non-ghost droplet but still have access to the ghost backend to write articles with the editor?

I don't fully understand how this works. Any advice is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a confusion around theming in Ghost and using Ghost as a Headless CMS. When you use the Ghost Content API to retrieve content, such as using it to pull content into a Next.js application, you're using Ghost as a Headless CMS.

Because the head, your front-end Next.js application, is detached from Ghost you no longer need to deal with the theming part of Ghost. The default Ghost theme can be left as it is, and the site can be set to Private mode (see General settings in Ghost admin).

A Next.js application can effectively be hosted anywhere, but Vercel is probably the most suitable as that's designed for hosting these sorts of applications.